# Remove a Timer from List<Timer> in runtime C#

Tags: c#, arrays, controls

I'm trying to remove a Timer component from a List -

```
foreach (Timer timer in timers)
{
    if (timer.Tag.ToString()=="mytag")
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;

        timer.Tick -= OnTimerTick;
        timers.Remove(timer);
    }
}
```

But it gives error-

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

Any help?

Comment: Why don't you use `List<Timer>`?

Comment: @dotnetom - good idea. Let's try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For unknown size you should use a list instead of an array.

Try `List<Timer> timers = new List<Timer>();`

[Edit] You just changed the whole question to a new one after this answer.
You can't remove an item inside a foreach loop. You could use a duplicate for that list or simply iterate backwards:

```
for (int i = timers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (timers[i].Tag.ToString()=="mytag")
    {
        timers[i].Enabled = false;
        timers[i].Tick -= OnTimerTick;
        timers.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: @s.k.paul You can't modify a list while iterating over it with `foreach`. If you need to delete or add something while in the loop, create a temporary list to add the item you need to destroy, then outside the loop destroy them based on that list.

Comment: @VaughanHilts - Would you post a sample code please?

Comment: @s.k.paul It won't be easy in comments -- this is another problem but the gist is: `foreach(var timer in timers) { timersToRemove.Add(timer); }` and then right outside the loop you do `foreach(var timer in timersToRemove) { timers.remove(timer); }`

Comment: @VaughanHilts - Why not post it as answer?

Comment: @s.k.paul I've posted the code to help you -- but it's inherently different from what you originally asked.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please don't change the whole question after it was answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a collection in a `foreach` like that in C#. You can work around this by changing:

```
 foreach (Timer timer in timers)
    {
        if (timer.Tag.ToString()=="mytag")
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;

            timer.Tick -= OnTimerTick;
            timers.Remove(timer);
        }
    }
```

To this instead:

```
var timersToRemove = new List<Timer>();
foreach (Timer timer in timers)
    {
        if (timer.Tag.ToString()=="mytag")
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;

            timer.Tick -= OnTimerTick;
            timersToRemove.Add(timer);
        }
    }

foreach(var timer in timersToRemove)
   timers.Remove(timer);
// Clear the list
timersToRemove.Clear();
```